# Saving CheckBox state with SQLite Database

Tags: java, android, sqlite, fragment, adapter

I'm building a list app that uses a SQLite database to hold list items. A list item consists of a UUID, name and boolean value to determine whether or not its is solved (database stores it as an int). What I've noticed is that when a user checks a task off and a new task is added the list is reloaded so that the checked tasks are now unchecked. In addition, when the app is restarted the list is reloaded so all tasks that were checked become unchecked.

Now I've been thinking of ideas and so far what I've done is in my TaskAdapter class in the onBindViewHolder() method I call setOnCheckedChangedListener() so that when a user checks off a task a toast is launched. I feel like I should be doing something here to update that specific task in the database, but I don't know how.

Additional notes: I'm using a singleton class where I have all my database methods like adding a task, updating a task and retrieving all the tasks from the database.

**ListFragment.java**

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment implements AddTaskDialog.addTask{

private static final String ADD_TASK_TAG = "ADD_TASK_DIALOG";
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private TaskAdapter mAdapter;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);

    mRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    updateUI();

    return view;
}

private void updateUI(){
    List<Task> tasks = TaskLab.getTaskLab(getContext()).getTaskList();

    if(mAdapter == null) {
        mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(tasks);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }else{
        mAdapter.setTaskList(tasks);
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.toolbar_layout,menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case R.id.add_task_button:
            // Launch a dialog.
            AddTaskDialog dialog = new AddTaskDialog();
            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
            dialog.setTargetFragment(ListFragment.this,1);
            dialog.show(manager,ADD_TASK_TAG);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }
}

// Part of the addTask interface created in AddTaskDialog
@Override
public void addTask(String taskName) {
    Task task = new Task();
    task.setName(taskName);
    TaskLab.getTaskLab(getContext()).addTask(task);
    updateUI();
}
}
```

**TaskAdapter.java**

```
public class TaskAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TaskAdapter.TaskHolder> {

private List<Task> mTaskList;

public TaskAdapter(List<Task> tasks){
    mTaskList = tasks;
}
@Override
public TaskAdapter.TaskHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item_layout,parent,false);
    return new TaskHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(TaskAdapter.TaskHolder holder, int position) {
    Task task = mTaskList.get(position);
    holder.bindData(task);

    holder.mTaskCheckBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            if(isChecked){
                Toast.makeText(compoundButton.getContext(),"Task Solved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mTaskList.size();
}

public void setTaskList(List<Task> tasks) {
    mTaskList = tasks;
}

public class TaskHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView mTaskName;
    private CheckBox mTaskCheckBox;

    public TaskHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTaskName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_name);
        mTaskCheckBox = itemView.findViewById(R.id.task_checkbox);
    }

    private void bindData(Task task) {
        mTaskName.setText(task.getName());
        mTaskCheckBox.setChecked(task.isSolved());
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
    }
}


}
```

**TaskLab.java** (Singleton class)

```
public class TaskLab {

private static TaskLab sTaskLab;
private Context mContext;

private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

private TaskLab(Context context) {
    mContext = context.getApplicationContext();
    mDatabase = new TaskBaseHelper(mContext).getWritableDatabase();
}

public static TaskLab getTaskLab(Context context){
    if(sTaskLab == null) {
        sTaskLab = new TaskLab(context);
    }

    return sTaskLab;
}

// Add DataBase operation method here.

private ContentValues getContentValues(Task task) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TaskTable.Cols.UUID, task.getId().toString());
    values.put(TaskTable.Cols.NAME, task.getName());
    values.put(TaskTable.Cols.SOLVED, task.isSolved() ? 1 : 0);

    return values;
}

public void addTask(Task task) {
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(task);
    mDatabase.insert(TaskTable.TABLE_NAME,null,values);
}

// Don't really understand this method
public void updateTask(Task task) {
    String uuidString = task.getId().toString();
    ContentValues values = getContentValues(task);

    mDatabase.update(TaskTable.TABLE_NAME,values, TaskTable.Cols.UUID + " = ?",
            new String[] {uuidString});
}

public TaskCursorWrapper queryTasks(String whereClause, String[] whereArgs) {
    Cursor cursor = mDatabase.query(TaskTable.TABLE_NAME,null,whereClause,whereArgs,null,null,null);
    return new TaskCursorWrapper(cursor);
}

public List<Task> getTaskList(){

    List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<>();
    TaskCursorWrapper cursor = queryTasks(null,null);

    try{
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            Task task = cursor.getTask();
            taskList.add(task);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
    }finally {
        cursor.close();
    }

    return taskList;
}
```

Comment: You can use any boolean parameter in your model class.
And set checkbox state in this boolean parameter. And that parameter value you can save in database. When you want to get value from database just check boolean value and set that boolean value in checkbox.

Comment: @HardikVaghasiya I do have a boolean parameter in my model class. Its just that I can't access the database from my adapter class because my database is stored in TaskLab (a singleton class). If I could somehow access that database then I can just call the updateTask() method from TaskLab and that would get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

In adapter, when u use onclick, the current item will update, but while scrolling the position of clicked check box will mismatch. Because adapter consider only the position which u have written from ur code. So please use any getter/setter to avoid this issue.